# Salary calculator

Tags: java, finance

The specifications are:

The first 36 hours worked are paid at a rate of 15.0, then the next 5 hours are paid at a rate of 15 * 1.5. Hours after that up to a max of 48 are paid at a rate of 15 * 2.

It works, but I'm new and might've gone about this in a complicated fashion.

```
import java.util.*;

class Task3
{
public static void main()
{
    // Scanner object
    Scanner inputText = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Variables
    double hoursWorked, pay = 15, overtime, totalPay = 0;
    String employee;

    // Ask user for employees name
    System.out.println ("Enter employee's name");
    employee = inputText.nextLine();

    // Ask user for employees weekly hours worked
    System.out.println ("Type in the total hours worked this week:");
    hoursWorked = inputText.nextDouble();

    overtime = hoursWorked;

    if (hoursWorked <= 36)
    {
        totalPay = hoursWorked * pay;
    }        
    else if (hoursWorked > 36 && hoursWorked <= 41)
    {
        totalPay += 36 * pay;
        hoursWorked -=36;
        overtime = hoursWorked * pay * 1.5;
        totalPay += overtime;
        hoursWorked += 36;
    }
    else
    {
        totalPay += 36 * pay;
        hoursWorked -= 36;
        overtime = hoursWorked * pay * 1.5;
        totalPay += overtime;
        hoursWorked -=5;
        overtime = hoursWorked * pay * 0.5;
        totalPay += overtime;
        hoursWorked += 41;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `try-with-resources`

Since Java 7, it's recommend to use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on `AutoCloseable`  instances, e.g. `Scanner` in this case, for safe and efficient handling of the underlying I/O resource.

## Methods

The calculation itself can be encapsulated into a method:

```
private static double getPay(double hoursWorked) {
    // calculation
}
```

Given that, your `main()` method can be refactored as such:

```
public static void main() {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println ("Enter employee's name");
        employee = inputText.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("Type in the total hours worked this week:");
        hoursWorked = getDouble(scanner);
        System.out.println("Total pay: " + getPay(hoursWorked));
    }
}
```

`getDouble(Scanner)` is a helper method that performs some basic validation on getting a `double` value from the `Scanner` instance by calling its `hasNextDouble()` method first, for example:

```
private static double getDouble(Scanner scanner) {
    while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input, enter a number.");
        scanner.next();
    }
    return scanner.nextDouble();
}
```

Of course, you may want to perform extra validation, for example making sure that the input is a positive number.

## Hard-coding (and approach)

```
else if (hoursWorked > 36 && hoursWorked <= 41)
```

The `41` is not immediately obvious from the problem statement, because that's really just adding the **next 5 hours (are paid...)** to the initial 36 hours. You should avoid the hard-coding and instead rely more on declaring suitable constants so that it's easier to update these values in the future.

You can also avoid unnecessary subtractions and additions above the base hours to `hoursWorked` for the following reaons:

1. Since your approach is self-contained per `if` clause (as opposed to a 'waterfall'-like approach), you can simply perform the one or two subtractions required to obtain the reminder hours for multiplication with the extra rates.
2. When the hours worked is above the base hours, you can simply calculate the base pay to be that multiplied with the base rate. When the hours worked is above the base hours *and* that 5 hours mentioned, the new 'base' pay is the original *plus* the multiplication of 5 hours with the overtime rate.
3. When you use methods, the original value `hoursWorked` is still preserved in the `main()` method. This remedies point 1 as well.

## Putting it altogether

```
private static final int BASE_HOURS = 36;
private static final int STEP = 5;
private static final int MAX_HOURS = 48;
private static final double BASE_RATE = 15.0;
private static final double STEP_MULTIPLIER = 1.5;
private static final double MAX_MULTIPLIER = 2.0;

private static double getPay(double hoursWorked) {
    if (hoursWorked > MAX_HOURS) {
        // perhaps not as dramatic as below, 
        // but this should be handled appropriately too?
        // System.err.println("Overworked!!! Quitting...");
        // System.exit(1);
    }
    if (hoursWorked <= BASE_HOURS) {
        return /* ... */ ;
    } else if (hoursWorked <= BASE_HOURS + STEP) {
        return /* ... */ ;
    } else {
        return /* ... */ ;
    }
}
```